Singular locus of analytic variety
Suppose $X$ is a complex manifold and $V \subseteq X$ is an analytic subvariety of $X$, i.e., $V$ is locally the zero locus of a finite collection of holomorphic functions. A point $x \in V$ is a smooth point if $V$ is a complex submanifold of $X$ near $x$. The singular locus $V_s$ is the subset of $V$ consisting of all non-smooth points.
It is proven on p. 21 of Griffiths & Harris that the singular locus $V_s$ is contained in a proper analytic subvariety of $V$. The beginning of the proof is as follows:

For $p \in V$, let $k$ be the largest integer such that there exist $k$ functions $f_1, \dots, f_k$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ vanishing on $V$ and such that $J(f)$ has a $k \times k$ minor not everywhere singular on $V$; we may assume that $|(\partial f_i / \partial z_i)_{1 \leq i, j \leq k}| \not\equiv 0$ on $V$. Let $U' \subseteq U$ be the locus of $|(\partial f_i / \partial z_i)_{1 \leq i, j \leq k}| \neq 0$ and $V'$ the locus $f_1 = \cdots = f_k = 0$. Then $\color{red}{V' = V \cap U'}$ is a complex submanifold of $U'$...

I am not sure how to justify the highlighted claim $V' = V \cap U'$. I am assuming they have defined $V'$ as the zero locus of the functions $f_1, \dots, f_k$ in $U'$, in which case it is clear that $V' \subseteq V \cap U'$. For the reverse inclusion, one needs to show that if $f_1(q) = \cdots = f_k(q) = 0$ and $J(f)$ has full rank at $q$, then $q \in V$.
However, I would like to ask the following easier question:

Question: Why does there exist a function $f$ defined near $p$ which vanishes on $V$ near $p$, such that $df$ is not identically zero on $V$?

Note that the existence of such $f$ is implicit in Griffiths & Harris' proof above, since otherwise we have $k = 0$ and the statement $V' = V \cap U$ is clearly false. However, I'm not sure how to show that $f$ exists when $p$ is a singular point. (When $p$ is a smooth point, then $f$ exists by definition.)
